# Trying to align several dojo componenets

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, web

Ok, so I am adding a bunch of different dojo components to a table

```
<table>

<tr><td> DOJO COMPONENT 1 </td></tr>

<tr><td> DOJO COMPONENT 2 </td></tr>

<tr><td> DOJO COMPONENT 3 </td></tr>

</table>
```

All components are input components like text box, text area, date box, checkbox

But it comes out wierd like this:

```
Name:[                  ]
Address:[                  ]
Date of Birth:[                   ]
```

I want the input fields to be aligned so it looks something like this, I want the input field to adjust.

```
Name:          [                        ]
Address:       [                        ]
Date of Birth: [                        ]
```

I do not want to set the label width of each dojo component to a certain value (like 400 px), although it is a solution.

Below is the properties i set for each component:

```
                        dijit.byId("${attr.id}").set({
                                    label: "${attr.name}",
                                    labelAlignment: "horizontal",
                                    fieldWidth : 400
                                });
```

Ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Please include a js fiddle for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the dojox.layout.TableContainer widget, it does exactly what you are looking for :)